# Is there a device / software that tracks a wallet?

Tags: tracking

Good afternoon all,

I was wondering is there any device that can be attached to a wallet so that in case the wallet is dropped, it is still *trackable* ?

Comment: Not so high-tech solution: long wallet and chain.

Comment: @iglvzx perhaps a long chain and wallet? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.loc8tor.com

[image: loc8tor tag]

Comment: Wow this is cool stuff! Btw just wondering, is there something better (no 183m range limit) like a device that tracks its own location and uploads it onto the web so that as long as it is running it is trackable?

Comment: @Pacerier: See their GPS tracker products.

Answer (score 0):

There are trackers that use GPS for positioning, and GSM for communicating. But I have not seen any wallet-sized. Think of the smallest mobile phone. You need most of the stuff in that, plus a GPS receiver.

Also, GPS does not work very well indoors, or even in cars away from the windshield.

Comment: Do you mean to say that this technology (putting a *tracker* in a wallet to know of its location) does not exist as of now?

Comment: No, I am saying that the technology exists, just not small enough to put in my wallet. You can of course get a bigger wallet.